# Adjust probabilities to make it equal to 1

Tags: probability, distributions

Is there a way to normalize the given probabilities? Let's say for example I have this probability for the following words:

```
                              I    am     the   best   today
```

$$1/5 + 1/5 + 1/5 + 1/5 + 1/5 = 1$$

Given that people typed the word

```
am
```

50% of the time, the distribution would adjust to

$$ 1/5 + 1/2 + 1/5 + 1/5 + 1/5$$
It is obvious that the equation wouldn't be equal to $1$. How can I force the equation to give a distribution wherein the probability of am would stay at $1/2$ while the others would adjust to make the equation be equal to $0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you correctlly, you want "am" to have 0.5 probability, keep relations between other probabilities and make all probabilities sum to 1. Am I right?

If so, you should first normalize the four probabilities you want to normalize to make them sum to 1. You can do this by dividing them by their sum (0.2/0.8 and all four probabilities would be 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25).

Then you can compute, that all other probabilities except probability of "am" should sum to 0.5 (because 1 - 0.5). Then you should multiplicate every of the remaining probabilities by this 0.5.

So result would be 0.25*0.5=0.125 and all probabilities would be: 0.125, 0.5, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125.